# Undefined Citation in sharelatex

Tags: citing, sharelatex

I'm trying to write my thesis using Latex, but I keep getting an undefined citations warning.

I've divided the thesis into chapters (each in their own folder) and each of the chapters into the sections that make it up for example, the folder "Chapter 4" contains a chapter4.tex file that is a chapter class document and uses input to collate all the sections, which are introduction, methods, results and discussion. None of the sections have a document class. There is then the main.tex file which collates all the chapters and creates the bibliography (I want one bibliography for all chapters).

The references are stored in a number of .bib files that I imported from Mendeley. All these .bib files are stored in the root directory So when I call the bibliography function in main.tex I use multiple input arguments as such:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{Residual_Inhibition_Studies,Neurostimulation_Studies,General,Tinnitus,Forward_Masking_Studies}
```

When I use \cite in one of my sections (intro, methods etc.) it allows for autocomplete/search to the reference I want, but when I compile it says it is undefined. Figures (which are in their own folder) work fine, just not the references.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I'm new to latex so apologies if the answer is obvious but I can't find anything about this particular problem elsewhere either.

Sorry that this question is so long. I couldn't think of a way to write an example code so I just have to describe it.

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, but are you compiling main.tex or chapterX.tex directly?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have the exact same issue... It looks like it's some kind of cache that needs to be cleared? Did you find a solution for this? Oh Nevermind! the solution is to **clear the cache**: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Kb/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida I am not sure, the question is very unclear. But if i understand the OP right, there are several standalone documents involved, not having a bibliography is quite expected.